# The django templates language judgement if is abnormality.

Tags: python, django

My code in the `views.py`:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'age':37})
```

This is the `if` templates judgement in the django templates example:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        {% if age > 25 %}
        <span> >25 </span>
        {% elif age > 30 %}
        <span> >30 </span>
        {% elif age > 35 %}
        <span> >35 </span>
        {% else %}
        <span> other </span>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>
```

But however if I refresh the safira there all prints `>25`, not `>35`, why?

Comment: The first if statement is true. What do you expect? It just stops to iterate once a statement is true.

Comment: The Logic You have written is wrong<br> ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of Logic should be as below:

```
<tr>
    <td>{% if age > 35 %}
            <span> >35 </span>
        {% elif age > 30 %}
            <span> >30 </span> 
        {% elif age > 25 %}
            <span> >25 </span>
        {% else %}
            <span> other </span>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dind't specify the if well enough. The script will go over the if's from top to bottom and the first one that is True will execute the code belonging to that if statement and then exit the if block. So your first 'if' is True as 37 is greater than 25 and will exit, ignoring the other elifs.

It would have been better if state your conditions more precisely greater than x and smaller than y etc.

Comment: Hmmm, I see that the accepted answer has no explanation, but just rewrites the code and and this is down voted, while offering an explanation, leaving the writing of the code to the asker. Don't know why this downvote was required, please explain.

Comment: Not a down-voter, but you haven't actually provided a solution, just identified where the problem is.

Comment: "But however if I refresh the safira there all prints >25, not >35, why?"
Seems to me that that was the question.